# Show loading icon with custom tool using ASP.NET and ArcGIS Server

Tags: arcgis-server, .net, asp.net, arcgis-web-adf

I have a custom tool in vb.net for a web application, I'm using Asp.net, the class is in vb.net and the GIS service is in ArcGIS Server 9.3 sp1, the tool makes a selection of layers and takes a lot of time, so I want to show a loading icon on the map while it's getting the info from the server.

Any idea?

I already tried to modify the progress bar from the map but it works only within the map events, I want to show the progress bar from the custom class, from vb.net.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your quickest answer, is create a DIV on your page; set it to runas server, then hide it. So when you start your function go through and turn that div on, then when finished turn the div off.

I don't have any code I can quickly post for you; but I have done this all over the place in my COTS apps and the workflow is pretty solid.

Answer (score 1):

In the following link you have an example how to do exactly what you want but in the client side (including the CSS to set the div centered and grayed)

http://cs.asteryx.com/forums/p/40/55.aspx

Just do the same but instead of the ajax javascript , run the code to set it visibility on the server side.